# gpg remove passphrase

Tags: gnupg, pgp

I want to remove the passphrase from gpg key after creating it. Why? .
[Because the tigase-kontalk documentation says so](https://github.com/kontalk/tigase-kontalk/blob/master/docs/local-server-howto.md#create-gpg-key) and I want to compile and setup my own version of this server . But am stuck at this point

> Create GPG key Create a GPG key for both signing and encrypting, and
> remove its passphrase after creating it

I want a linux gpg command to remove the passphrase or to export unprotected keys.

Comment: If you just want to export an unprotected version of the secret key (and keep it passphrase-protected in your keyring), there is now a tool for that: https://github.com/pts/gpg-export-secret-key-unprotected

Answer (score 48):

Here is a more complete answer based on Justin's:

*(Using gpg 1.4.16 on Ubuntu 14)*

- Get the ID of your key like this:

```
gpg --list-secret-keys --keyid-format=long
```

This will output a few lines similar to below. The key ID is the value XXXX

```
/home/username/.gnupg/secring.gpg
----------------------------------
sec   4096R/XXXX <creation date>
uid                  name <email.address>
ssb   4096R/YYYY <creation date>
```

- Open the gpg key edit submenu like this:

  `gpg --edit-key XXXX`

  You will see information about the key.
- Type `passwd` at the prompt to change the password:

  `gpg> passwd`
- Enter your existing passphrase.
- Enter the new passphrase for this secret key. (Leave this blank and press Enter)
- Press <kbd>Enter</kbd> twice and consider the warnings from the tool and its implications before proceeding.

```
    You don't want a passphrase - this is probably a *bad* idea!

    Do you really want to do this? (y/N) y
```

---

Similarly On Debian 11:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: This doesn't work for me : Debian 11 ARM64 inside Qemu

Comment: I had to use `gpg --list-secret-keys --keyid-format=long` to get the XXXX key

Comment: @Sr.PEDRO You don't have to use the  shortened XXXX value after the /. The full key ID on the next line works too.

Comment: @EkaterinaIvanovaiceja.net I was able to get it to work on my Debian 11 instance.
https://imgur.com/a/sGBFFel

Answer (score 22):

Let me share what I found. I thought I might share in case there is another lost soul
In the bash shell,

```
gpg2 --batch --gen-key <<EOF
%no-protection
Key-Type:1
Key-Length:2048
Subkey-Type:1
Subkey-Length:2048
Name-Real: My super name
Name-Email: admin@superuser.com
Expire-Date:0
EOF
```

The key can now be exported

```
gpg2 --export-secret-key fingerprinthere > private-key.key
gpg2 --export fingerprintshuld_be_put_here > public-key.key
```

Comment: The trick is %no-protection

Comment: Your question was how to "remove" a passphrase on a key after creating it. This answer, however, is for how to create it without a passphrase to start with.

Comment: This answer doesn't answer the original question. The OP already has a passphrase-protected secret key in their keyring, and they want to remove the protection.

Comment: with `gpg 2.2.27` this was the only solution that worked to generate keys for an automated environment

Answer (score 9):

It's simple. Just run:

```
gpg --edit-key <yourkeyhere>
passwd
```

When GnuPG prompts for the new passphrase, just leave it blank and hit enter.

Source: https://lists.gnupg.org/pipermail/gnupg-users/2003-April/017623.html

Comment: This doesn't work. It returns error `gpg: key key B64F361BF49F2E74/B64F361BF49F2E74: error changing passphrase: No passphrase given`

Comment: It worked for me (Ubuntu 16.04, GPG 1.4.20). At the end you need to save the key with `save`

Comment: It doesn't work for me either.

Comment: This doesn't work on gpg 1.4.16. It lists some information about the key and puts you into a gpg submenu.

Comment: This works with GPG 1.4 (I've just tried it with 1.4.16). It also works with GPG 2.1.18. I suspect it was broken in earlier GPG 2.0--2.1.x.

Answer (score 3):

See https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/597949/20960. It seems that some varieties of pinentry refuse to accept an empty passphrase, while others are fine with it.

`gpg --pinentry-mode loopback --passwd KEY`

Comment: With gpg 2.2.40 on Debian (Trixie) this does not work anymore, neither with `--edit-key` and `passwd`, nor with `--passwd`. It seems GnuPG intentionally removed all options to export an unencrypted secret key.

Comment: like Michal, this used to work and now it doesn't. However `--edit-key` worked for me, by entering an empty and saying yes twice. https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/550538/606003